# TemplateUrl, ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, ngroute

I have a problem with my code:

```js
var app = angular.module( "myApp", ['ngRoute'] );

app.config( function ( $routeProvider ) {
  $routeProvider
    .when( '/home', { templateUrl: 'strony/home.html' } )
    .when( '/about', { templateUrl: 'strony/about.html' } )
    .when( '/contact', { templateUrl: 'strony/contact.html' } )
    .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/this' } );
});

app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

and i have three html positions in folder: 'strony'. If i click on link adress name is changing but on site nothing happenes. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Is the path in `templateUrl` correct?

Comment: Yes, this looks like: 
-index.html
-script.js
-strony/
*home.html
*about.html
*contact.html

Comment: At what path is ur app.js?

Comment: Do you see errors in the browser console?